# PHP/javascript: How to load the current page using DOMDocument loadHTMLFile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I wouldn't normally post here as I can normally find answers by reading other posts that have already been answered. But, I've been stuck on this for days now. I am a very beginner level coder but have experience with javascript, php, html, css, and ajax. I've tried loadHTMLFile, xpath->query, and cURL. I'll leave everything I've already tried commented out in my code below.

Here's the scenario. User enters name, email, birth date, birth time, and birth city into a form. That information is then used to generate a personalized page for the user that is dynamically generated. The URL is getting dynamically generated as well:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'et_pb_signup_firstname');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'et_pb_signup_email');
$year = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '_year');
$month = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '_month');
$day = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '_day');
$hour = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '_hour');
$minutes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '_minutes');
$location = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '_location');
$timezone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, '_timezone);

$my_post = array(
     'post_title' => $name . '-Personalized-Report-' . $month . $day . $year . $hour . $minutes . '_' . $encrypted_data,
     'post_content'  => '[bgc_chart]',
     'post_status'   => 'publish',
     'post_author'   => 1,
     'post_category' => '',
     'post_type'     => 'page',
     'post_name'     => $name . '-Personalized-Report-' . $month . $day . $year . $hour . $minutes    
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

$target_page = strtolower('http://orionohev.com/' . $name . '-Personalized-Report-' . $month . $day . $year . $hour . $minutes);

$_SESSION['_bgc_data'] = $data;

$response = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'redirect_to' => $target_page
```

This is all working correctly.

The page is getting generated correctly. During the generation process, I am populating the value of the  tag with the encrypted data as seen above, delimited by "_". This will be decrypted later to dynamically generate the page whenever a user goes to the provided URL.

When the browser is redirected to $target_page, the [bgc_chart] shortcode results in the bgc_chart_shortcode function being called, shown below. The reason I'm going through all this is because I need to email the user a link to their personalized generated report. And the report needs to be generated upon load of the page each time (unless there's a way to take the dynamically generated HTML and then hardcode it in place of the [bgc_chart] shortcode, which I don't know a way to do):

```
function bgc_chart_shortcode() {
    ob_start();

    $data = $_SESSION['_bgc_data'];
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $href = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    debug_to_console($href);
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($href);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');
    foreach ($tags as $h1){
        debug_to_console("here");
        $title = $h1->nodeValue;
        debug_to_console($title);
    }
```

The debug_to_console function is this:

```
function debug_to_console($data) {
    $output = $data;
    if (is_array($output))
        $output = implode(',', $output);

    echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
}
```

The URL is being output to the console correctly. It is the URL of the current page and matches correctly. But the "foreach ($tags as $h1){" loop is never entered into and I can't figure out why.

I've also tried xpath and all of these different things:

```
//$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
//$h1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0)->nodeValue;
//$h1 = $xpath->query('//h1[@class="entry-title main-title"]');

//$title = $h1->item(0)->nodeValue;
//debug_to_console($title);

// $tags = $xpath->query('//h1[contains(@class="entry-title")]');
/*        foreach($tags as $container) {
            $arr = $container->getElementsByTagName("h1");
            foreach($arr as $item) {
                $title_text = $item->nodeValue;
                debug_to_console($title_text);
            }
        }
  */  

// $item = $title->getElementsByTagName("h1")->nodeValue;
//debug_to_console($item);

// $title = $tags->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //debug_to_console($title);
```

I've also tried cURL but couldn't get it to work and, from what I've read in other posts, it's overkill and unneccessary. And, if I understand how DOM works, I don't think it's necessary.

Here's some sample HTML of the dynamically generated page:

```
<body class="page-template-default page page-id-2530 et_pb_button_helper_class et_fixed_nav et_show_nav et_primary_nav_dropdown_animation_fade et_secondary_nav_dropdown_animation_fade et_header_style_left et_pb_footer_columns4 et_cover_background et_pb_gutter et_pb_gutters3 et_right_sidebar et_divi_theme et-db">
    <div id="page-container">
        <header id="main-header" data-height-onload="66">
            <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
                <div class="logo_container">
                    <span class="logo_helper"></span>
                    <a href="http://orionohev.com/">
                    <img src="http://orionohev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/test.jpg" width="300" height="50" alt="Orion Ohev" id="logo" data-height-percentage="54" /></a>
                </div>
                <div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="66" data-fixed-height="40">
                    <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                    <ul id="top-menu" class="nav"><li id="menu-item-2180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2180"><a href="https://portal.test.com/public/form/view/6079b394cfc3b4081fb36885">Work With Me</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1733" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type "><a href="http://test.com">TAP School of Unlearning</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom"><a href="http://test.com">Log In</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-178" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-178"><a href="https://calendly.com/test">FREE SESSION</a></li>
</ul></nav>
            </div>
        </div>
            
    </header>
<div id="et-main-area">
    
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
                <div id="left-area">
                     <article id="post-2530" class="post-2530 page type-page status-publish hentry">
                     <h1 class="entry-title main_title">test888-Personalized-Report-010120210000_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</h1>
        <div class="entry-content">
```

---

I should say that that long string DID post to the console ONCE. But I don't know how and couldn't recreate it. I got excited because I thought I stumbled into the solution. But I'm not sure what happened. Or how. And I couldn't do it again.

I feel SO stuck and imagine for a more seasoned coder, this is a simple solution. Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a very odd way to go about the problem of presenting your users with their own personalised report. Rather than embedding an encrypted string within the page - or without actually creating an html page for each user (which is sort of how I interpreted this) surely it would be easier to build the page dynamically for every user when he/she enters their unique url?
If you want to use `DOMDocument` & `DOMXPath` to load and process the same page that the user is viewing you need to enable `output buffering` and load the buffer into `DOMDocument`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thank you for your comment and answer! I'm going to check out the answer now. Can you point me to a resource that would explain how I could build a page dynamically based on a unique URL? 

I bet it probably is easier! I was just trying to think of a solution and DOM was the only thing I could think of. This code I'm editing is part of a plugin that only generates the personalized report based on the $_SESSION. And every user gets the same URL. If there is no $_SESSION data, it defaults to my homepage.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius So I was trying to find a way to store the html that is dynamically generated during the $_SESSION, encrypt it into a string, save that string into the html of a dynamically generated page for each person. And then, on load of that page, decrypting the data to mimic it being from the current $_SESSION. I hope that makes sense. I am definitely open to easier solutions!

Comment: When the user completes and submits the form the information is being stored in the db presumably - save a unique, strong and cryptographically secure hash along with that record and use that hash in the url presented to your user. When the user visits that url the hash is used to perform the database lookup - the page is then rendered with the information directly from the database.

Comment: The info is not being stored in the DB. It is being sent to a 3rd party API, never to be seen again unless I store it somewhere to be reloaded. 

$data = wp_remote_get(add_query_arg([
    'api_key' => get_option('_bgc_api_key'),
    'date' => sprintf('%s-%s-%s %s:%s', $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minutes),
    'timezone' => $timezone
   ], 'https://api.bodygraphchart.com/v210502/hd-data'));
$data = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($data));
`code`

Comment: Then, it looks for one page on my site that has the [bgc_chart] shortcode:
`code`

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_content LIKE '%[bgc_chart]%' AND post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 1");

     if ($results) {
      $target_page = get_permalink($results[0]->ID) ;
     }*/
`code`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius

and does the following:

add_shortcode('bgc_chart', 'bgc_chart_shortcode');

 function bgc_chart_shortcode() {
  ob_start();
        if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
   session_start();
  }
  $data = $_SESSION['_bgc_data'];

... ... 

if (!isset($data->Properties)) {
   wp_redirect(home_url('/'));

   exit;
  }

`code` 

so if there is no data in the current session, it redirects to the homepage.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius So, where I"ve been stuck is that I need to email each person their individual chart. So I need to store the data somewhere to be dynamically loaded. Since, there won't be any data gathered from a form in the current session.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thank you for your support in your answer. Can you help me understand how to do this with loadHTMLFile? I don't believe loadHTML will work. I've tried it many times. I won't be able to add the PHP code to the file where the html is. The php is in a separate file. The HTML I need will be on the dynamically generated current page in the browser. I'm trying to use LoadHTMLFile to get that html. That is where I've been stuck. Thank you.

Comment: I'm almost positive there's a better way. Perhaps I can add to the DB on my side instead of creating a new page every time. e.g. storing the date, time, location, and encrypted string in the DB? I just feel a little lost and overwhelmed. I thought this was going to be easy to encrypt and decrypt a string. I really do appreciate your help. Is there a good tutorial page here on stackoverflow for the DB solution, if you think it's a better solution? Or, perhaps, after reading all of this, loadHTMLFile is the better solution?

Comment: I am not familiar with `WordPress` at all but `$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);` suggests to me a database insert. Your site is using Wordpress so there MUST be a database at the backend I believe.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I really do appreciate all of your help. But I feel a DB is too complicated for me. Is there any chance you can help me understand how to implement the answer you provided below but with loadHTMLFile instead of loadHTML. That was really the main question I had in this thread. loadHTML doesn't work. I need to pull the HTML from the current page of the browser as I mentioned in my comment on your answer below. 

I apologize for all the back and forth. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate how you can load the same page and fudge around with the content using DOMDocument the following might prove useful - though I still struggle to understand why the problem is being done in this manner...

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    @ini_set('output_buffering','On');
    @set_time_limit(0);
    @ob_start();
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Load same page and mangle using DOMDocument...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
    
        <div id="page-container">
            <header id="main-header" data-height-onload="66">
                <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
                    <div class="logo_container">
                        <span class="logo_helper"></span>
                        <a href="http://orionohev.com/">
                            <img src="http://orionohev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/test.jpg" width="300" height="50" alt="Orion Ohev" id="logo" data-height-percentage="54" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="66" data-fixed-height="40">
                        <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                            <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
                                <li id="menu-item-2180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2180"><a href="https://portal.test.com/public/form/view/6079b394cfc3b4081fb36885">Work With Me</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1733" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type "><a href="http://test.com">TAP School of Unlearning</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom"><a href="http://test.com">Log In</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-178" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-178"><a href="https://calendly.com/test">FREE SESSION</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="et-main-area">
                <div id="main-content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
                            <div id="left-area">
                                <article id="post-2530" class="post-2530 page type-page status-publish hentry">
                                <!--
                                
                                    This next h1 element will be targeted by DOMXPath and it's value will be mangled
                                    - this should show how you can load the same page with PHP and manipulate
                                    the contents stored therein. YOU would want to read and decrypt this value
                                    rather than simply add further text.
                                    
                                    -->
                                    <h1 class="entry-title main_title">test888-Personalized-Report-010120210000_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</h1>
                                    <div class="entry-content"></div>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    # suppress errors if possible
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
    
    # create the DOMDocument and load the buffer (the page content)
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( @ob_get_contents(), 'UTF-8' ) );
    
    libxml_clear_errors();

    # create the Xpath object to find the node of interest
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $expr='//h1[ contains( @class, "main_title" ) ]';
    $col=$xp->query( $expr );
    
    # found the node
    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
        
            #Do stuff with the node contents... 
            $node->nodeValue='MANGLE.... DECRYPT.... KABOOM!!!' . $node->nodeValue;
            
            # list($junk,$raw)=explode('_',$node->nodeValue);
            # $data=magically_decrypt($raw);
            # $node->nodeValue=$data; ... or whatever
        }
    }
    
    # save the HTML and flush the buffer
    $buffer=$dom->saveHTML();
    @ob_end_clean();
    exit( $buffer );
?>
```

---

To do the same thing with a previously saved HTML file rather than manipulating the same document ( as the question title suggests ) then:

**The HTML file - saved somewhere on the system**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>My Personal Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
    
        <div id="page-container">
            <header id="main-header" data-height-onload="66">
                <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
                    <div class="logo_container">
                        <span class="logo_helper"></span>
                        <a href="http://orionohev.com/">
                            <img src="http://orionohev.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/test.jpg" width="300" height="50" alt="Orion Ohev" id="logo" data-height-percentage="54" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="66" data-fixed-height="40">
                        <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                            <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
                                <li id="menu-item-2180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2180"><a href="https://portal.test.com/public/form/view/6079b394cfc3b4081fb36885">Work With Me</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1733" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type "><a href="http://test.com">TAP School of Unlearning</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom"><a href="http://test.com">Log In</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-178" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-178"><a href="https://calendly.com/test">FREE SESSION</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="et-main-area">
                <div id="main-content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
                            <div id="left-area">
                                <article id="post-2530" class="post-2530 page type-page status-publish hentry">
                                <!--
                                
                                    This next h1 element will be targeted by DOMXPath and it's value will be mangled
                                    - this should show how you can load the same page with PHP and manipulate
                                    the contents stored therein. YOU would want to read and decrypt this value
                                    rather than simply add further text.
                                    
                                    -->
                                    <h1 class="entry-title main_title">test888-Personalized-Report-010120210000_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</h1>
                                    <div class="entry-content"></div>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**The PHP to process that report file**

```
<?php

    /*
        The reports are stored in a sub-folder to the
        current executing script. As I say I do NOT
        use WordPress and have no idea how it structures
        a site at all so you need to figure out a suitable
        location to store files and the path to access.
    */
    $file=sprintf('%s/reports/joebloggs__personal_report.html',__DIR__);
    
    if( file_exists( $file ) ){
    
        libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
        
        $dom=new DOMDocument();
        $dom->validateOnParse=false;
        $dom->recover=true;
        $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
        $dom->loadHTMLFile( $file );
        $errors=libxml_get_errors();
        libxml_clear_errors();




        $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
        $expr='//h1[ contains( @class, "main_title" ) ]';
        $col=$xp->query( $expr );
        
        
        if( $col->length > 0 ){
            foreach( $col as $node ){
                list( $junk, $raw )=explode('_', $node->nodeValue );
                printf('Decrypt this: %s',$raw);
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Unable to load file';
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your support. Can you help me understand how to do this with loadHTMLFile? I don't believe loadHTML will work. I've tried it many times. I won't be able to add the PHP code to the file where the html is. The php is in a separate file. The HTML I need will be on the dynamically generated current page in the browser. I'm trying to use LoadHTMLFile to get that html. That is where I've been stuck. Thank you.

Comment: Your question title says `"How to load the current page using DOMDocument loadHTMLFile"` ~ ignoring the `loadHTMLFile` part you are still wanting to manipulate the current PHP page are you not? The above code does exactly that - but you cannot call `loadHTMLFile` to load the same page  afaik

Comment: no, i'm not trying to manipulate the current PHP page. This PHP file is a separate file from the HTML page. The HTML I'm trying to load exists at $href = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], which is the page that is redirected to by the PHP code to display the personalized report. The HTML isn't in the .php file. It's in the current page of the browser.

In my question title, "current page" meant the current page in the browser. I apologize for not being specific enough in the title. It is a separate page, so I think loadHTMLFile is needed, right?

Comment: I just realized I didn't tag you in the comment above.